# Open exe application wiith Arguments from Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I can easily open my application with arguments through RUN.  But I'm having issues trying to start my application with arguments as a hyperlink inside of microsoft word.  Is this possible?  If not, How can I open my application from inside a word document?

Path to application

```
"C:\Users\antonioc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NV_Dev\ServerInventory\ServerInventory\bin\Debug\ServerInventory.exe" -SERVERNAME="test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought of running it from a macro button field?  This would give users a clickable link, you could then shell launch application or any otherm,acro supported launch method through the macro.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/field-codes-macrobutton-field-HP005186171.aspx

Comment: I passed the parameter using a VBA macro button.  Thanks!